# iOS 9 - secureTextEntry Breaks UITextField Line Height

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField subclass that does some minor overrides of `textRectForBounds`, `editingRectForBounds`, and `placeholderRectForBounds`. The class works great for iOS 8.4 and lower. When iOS 9 was released, I realized that my password text field (with `secureTextEntry = YES`) exhibited some weird line height behavior:

[image: Proof]

As you can see in the first image, the placeholder rect and editing rect are properly centered. When I start typing though (2nd image) it appears to enlarge the editing rect and the text is shifted to the bottom rather than centered. Then finally in the 3rd image, you can see it re-centers after the final character becomes a bullet.

Is this a bug or have they just changed how secureTextEntry fields work now? Is there a workaround to make it appear like it used to before iOS 9?